# avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

Tags: arduino, ethernet

**avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00**

[image]

I'm using arduino uno with ethernet shield.

I plugged a Led from digital pin to GND directly without any resistor if that was the problem, I do it often so far if that was the cause it just broke down now.

I already did the following:

• Port check

• Board check

• Driver check / re-install

• Cable check / renewed

none of it seems to work. If it is broken would my ethernet shield be harmed and be broken as well? Which should I replace.

Comment: It would be worth removing the Ethernet shield and trying again.

Comment: nahh.already tried that, .

Comment: Related: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/18/37

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are using `Bluetooth`. Solution is pretty simple. Just plug off `TX` and `RX` cable from Arduino and then upload your code. Then plug them in again.That worked great for me. For more listen [this guy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXs7S048eIo).

Comment: Had the same issue with an APC220 component which makes use of TX and RX pins. Removed them and it worked just fine

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your board to Arduino UNO in "Tools" -> "Board" and also check the port =)

Answer (score 1):

I changed Tools->Programmer->AVR ISP and it works now fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload the Bootloader to solve the issue. This error come only when you have try to upload infinite loop program or boot loader crashed.

You need to upload boot loader using Avr pocket programmer to solve issue

```
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9825
```

Comment: really, .my only solution is to buy that or a new Arduino? I'm just buying arduino clone. I found out it works just as well.

Comment: it your wish. Usually the problem arises when boot loader crashed. i recommend to purchase above kit. it solve issue. If new arduino also face same problem , you cant do anything expect above step. Else replace IC with updated bootloader

Answer (score 0):

Check if the controller is placed oppositely on the board i.e. notched side being opposite of where it should be. That happened to me, gave the same error that couldn't be solved by anything. Just putting this here because the controller doesn't always just stop working if you do that, it might even give this error. Cheers.